# How to handle a situation when one microservice is out of order

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs, microservices, nestjs-microservice

How to handle a situation when the microservice of products is out of order and does not return a value?

```
async getStats(productId: string) {
    const existedProduct = await firstValueFrom(
        this.productClient.send('get_product', { productId })
    );

    if (!existedProduct) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Продукт не найден');
    }

    const avgRatingData = await this.prismaService.review.aggregate({
        where: { productId },
        _avg: {
            rate: true
        }
    });

    const reviewsCount = await this.prismaService.review.count({
        where: { productId }
    });

    const avgRating = avgRatingData._avg.rate ? Number(avgRatingData._avg.rate.toFixed(2)) : 0;

    return {
        stats: {
            productId,
            avgRating,
            reviewsCount
        }
    };
}
```

The problem is that if the product service fails, this code will wait for a response until it turns on again

```
const existedProduct = await firstValueFrom(
    this.productClient.send('get_product', { productId })
);
```

Comment: Hello, could you precisely describe the behavior that you expect from your `getStats` method when `this.productClient.send(...)` fails (bubbling up the error, retrying, ...) ?

Comment: I would like if another service does not respond for a long time, then assign existedProduct null

Answer (score 1):

I decided as follows:

```
const existedProduct = await firstValueFrom(
    this.productClient.send('get_product', { productId }).pipe(timeout(1000))
).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.message);
    return null;
});
```